# Custom dialer for smtp client in Golang?

Tags: go, proxy, smtp, socks

I'm try connect to smtp server via socks5 proxy

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "net/smtp"

    "golang.org/x/net/proxy"
)

func main() { Connect() }
func Connect() {
    dialer, err := Socks("127.0.0.1:9050", "smtp.gmail.com:465")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    client, err := smtp.NewClient(dialer, "smtp.gmail.com:465")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", "mymailaddr@gmail.com", "", "smtp.gmail.com:465")
    if err = client.Auth(auth); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func Socks(socks, addr string) (r net.Conn, err error) {
    Dial, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", socks, nil, proxy.Direct)
    r, err = Dial.Dial("tcp", addr)
    return
}
```

And can't it, have error

```
panic: EOF

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.Connect()
        main.go:18 +0x1e5
main.main()
        main.go:10 +0x20
exit status 2
```

Does `smtp.Client` can any method to connect smtp server with socks proxy? I'm not found answer in Google and not found any library provide this features.

Comment: You shouldn't ignore errors in your `Socks()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using port 465 which expects TLS from start (implicit TLS) and not the usual TLS after STARTTLS command (explicit TLS). This means that the `Conn` object you use as `dialer` should already have been upgraded to TLS. To do this:

```
import "crypto/tls"
...
func Connect() {
    dialer, err := Socks("127.0.0.1:9050", "smtp.gmail.com:465")
    ...
    conf := &tls.Config{ServerName: "smtp.gmail.com"}
    tlsdialer := tls.Client(dialer, conf)
    client, err := smtp.NewClient(tlsdialer, "smtp.gmail.com:465")
```

Alternatively you could use port 587 which requires explicit TLS:

```
func Connect() {
    dialer, err := Socks("127.0.0.1:9050", "smtp.gmail.com:587")
    ...
    conf := &tls.Config{ServerName: "smtp.gmail.com"}
    err = client.StartTLS(conf)
    ...
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", "mymailaddr@gmail.com", "", "smtp.gmail.com:587")
    if err = client.Auth(auth); err != nil {
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks you for help!

Comment: @АндрейАнтонов Did this work for you?
were you able to send email using GO smtp client behind proxy?

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Both of these two functions require the first parameter to be connection instead of a dialer: `tls.Client([connection], conf)` and `smtp.NewClient([connection],...)`. How did you do that?

Comment: @WildCat: don't let you confuse by the names of the variables. `dialer` as returned by `Socks` is a `Conn` and `tlsdialer` as returned by `tls.Client` is a `Conn` too. I've just used the naming scheme for variables from the original question in the answer.