# Is there any way to use proxy with go-simple-mail lib in Golang?

Tags: go, proxy, smtp

One project uses "github.com/xhit/go-simple-mail/v2" for sending mail through smtp.

Recently was tasked to add usage of proxy with this lib. But can't figure out how to do it.

Failed to find examples on Google or in lib itself. (

So I wander now if this is even possible with this lib or I should just use something else instead.

If it is possible with go-simple-mail, then working example would be much appreciated.

Update:
Considering comments so far decided to give a bit more info.

The goal is to hide sender IP in some cases(only is some cases). It's not a network task. It's smth I have to do in the code.

Generally speaking I need to tell create forward proxy and tell my app to use this forward proxy in some cases. But for smtp not http/https
I might have found one lib, that allows to do that. Checking it out at the moment. But I wander if there's some way to do it using go-simple-mail, cuz that's what people before me used.

Comment: Is that the same problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53236820/use-smtp-email-client-behind-proxy-in-go. You should set `proxy` in your machine, and make your program use it to transport.

Comment: The `github.com/xhit/go-simple-mail` lib mentions this in an issue([#24](https://github.com/xhit/go-simple-mail/issues/24)) too.

Comment: it is not the same problem, I saw that one; he is not trying to use any proxy, he an had issue with proxy settings in their company it seems; And my goal is to actually use to tell my program, that it should use a proxy in some cases and pass that proxy to it

Comment: on 2nd comment it seems, that there's no way to do it using go-simple-mail

Comment: I think we are discussing the `Outbound SMTP proxying` in [SMTP_proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_proxy)? Or you just need a custom dialer? Here I found in stw. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856084/custom-dialer-for-smtp-client-in-golang

Comment: yup, last one helped; it is useful to learn new stuff; it seems however that your first comment was correct, it's not even my service issue; right now trying to explain it to network administrators; they are fighting it as usual, cuz then they'll have to work )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly there's no other option on closing questions.

Comments from @spike014 helped.

Update: afterwards talked to creator of go-simple-mail and he allowed  to add necessary improvement. Will do it shortly. For now created my own lib based on go-simple-mail(License and author allow it). Works perfect. )